# Air 16 IPA Size exceeds maximum allowed size of 80MB

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, adobe

we have an app that was built using previous versions of Air, that ran in at 63 MB. Now with Air 16, it is suddenly 88 MB, and Apple no longer is accepting it. What could be the difference? And what can be done to reduce the size to the apple acceptable limit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you get this file size limit from? I believe the Apple limit is now 4GB.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02122015a